# Kendo Grid Export to PDF Remove grid css classes

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a grid that has alternating row color in it.  When exporting to pdf the I can remove the grid color through jquery, but the saveAsPDF function puts the color back in automatically and saves it with the color.  Is there a way to remove the row color on the grid so that the pdf that is generated doesn't contain the row color?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the CSS specifically for the Kendo Grid Export to PDF using `k-pdf-export` prefix, for example in order to set the color to white for all cells during the export:

```
.k-pdf-export .k-grid tr
{
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

This means no need to modify through jQuery. Runnable example in action [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/aPoLu).